# Plot function within an interval

Tags: matlab

I want to plot the function "y = 4.8643*x - 3.8559*x^2 + 1.1208*x^3 - 0.1348*x^4 + 0.0057*x^5" within x = 0 and x = 9. There should be 1000 intermediate values to make the function look smooth. I also want to plot the points from the function on the positions x = [0, 0.5, 1, 6, 7, 9] in the same window. How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [linspace](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) to generate the `x` values.

Then you can plot the function using the [plot](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function

You also have to modify the way you define the function by adding a `.` (a dot)
before the `^` operator in order to raise to the desired power the `x` values
`elementwise`

To also plot the specific `x` points, you can evaluate the `y` function on that points and then [image]either specify then in the 
same call to `plot` or to call again it after having set `hold on` to add the new data

```
% Generate the `x` values
x=linspace(0,9,1000)

% Evaluate the `y` function in the `[0 9]` interval
y = 4.8643*x - 3.8559*x.^2 + 1.1208*x.^3 - 0.1348*x.^4 + 0.0057*x.^5

% Define the set of `x` data
x1 = [0, 0.5, 1, 6, 7, 9] 

% Evaluate the `y` function in the new `x` interval
y1=4.8643*x1 - 3.8559*x1.^2 + 1.1208*x1.^3 - 0.1348*x1.^4 + 0.0057*x1.^5
```

Using a single call to plot

```
plot(x,y,x1,y1,'*')
grid on
```

Using two calls to plot

```
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(x1,y1,'*')
```